# Starman eat all the memory with Dancer REST api

Tags: perl, memory, dancer, plack, starman

I have developed a RESTful application with perl framework Dancer. This application needs almost 1 GB in memory and it takes 30 seconds to be loaded. This application works pretty well in a local test with `./bin/app.pl` for a single user, then I try to deploy with Starman (alone or with plackup, with and without keep-alive) for multi-tenant use in several different ways:

```
plackup -E production -s Starman --workers=10 -p 3000 -a bin/app.pl 
plackup -E production -s Starman --workers=10 -p 3000 -a bin/app.pl --disable-keepalive
plackup -E production -s Starman --workers=10 -p 3000 -a bin/app.pl --disable-keepalive --preload-app
starman --workers=10 -p 3000 -a bin/app.pl
```

Deployment success, but for each query Starman allocates some memory which never free
 any more, so the application go out of memory very fast.

I read all the documentation of Starman, PSGI and Dancer deployment, included a very nice explanation of [NGINX/Starman/Dancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127566/an-explanation-of-the-nginx-starman-dancer-web-stack) and a similar error with [Starman and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097926/why-is-raising-plackup-or-starman-memory-usage) but it doesn't solve this one, because I disable keep-alive and Starman still keep the memory.

Any idea why Starman is eating my memory? Thanks!

Comment: Does it consistently do this (a) with just one worker and (b) with repeated queries that "do nothing". That will show if it's Starman at fault or whatever your 1GB app is. If you need help troubleshooting a large, long-running Perl process it might be worth registering + posting at perlmonks.org where you can have a longer discussion.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your reply, this is far from a hot topic :) I will send my question to perlmonks as well, thanks.

I did the test you suggest:
a) Same thing, Starman allocate memory but don't free it; or course in this case Starman take less memory at the beggining because throw less processes (workers)
b) Same thing, in this case the memory is taken in tiny pieces but not freedom; same problem

I'm trying to test other web servers, but Starman seems the most popular by far. I will post here updates.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found where the memory leak was and I'm sorry Starman to blame you :)

In the program we use a binding library wich works perfect in a regular execution but for a reason I can't figure out, in a multiprocess situation eat all the memory. This bug have been sended to the author of the perl library.

Comment: Plack::MiddleWare::SizeLimit is a good plugin to kill and restart the processes if they use too much memory.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, can you expand on which library eats up the memory?